# Ambiguous overload for operator= using move assign and pass by value copy assign

Tags: c++, g++, move-semantics

If I define a copy assignment operator that invokes the copy constructor using pass by value for class `thing`:

```
thing& operator= (thing x) {
```

and a move assignment operator for the same class:

```
thing& operator= (thing&& x) {
```

Trying to invoke the move assignment results in an error from gcc:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘thing’ and ‘std::remove_reference<thing&>::type {aka thing}’)
```

However, if the copy assign instead uses pass by reference:

```
thing& operator= (thing& x) {
```

Compilation is fine, and both operators can be invoked.  Why is this?

Complete C++11 test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class thing {
    public:
        thing () { }
        thing (thing& x) {
            cout << "Copy constructor.\n";
        }
        thing (thing&& x) {
            cout << "Move constructor.\n";
        }
        thing& operator= (thing x) {
            cout << "Copy assign using pass by value.\n";
            return *this;
        }
        thing& operator= (thing&& x) {
            cout << "Move assign.\n";
            return *this;
        }
};


int main (void) {
    thing a, b;
// Invoke move assignment:
    a = move(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a special rule in overload resolution that rvalues of type `A` prefers to bind to `A&&` rather than `A&`. There's no corresponding rule for `A&&` vs `A`.

Comment: @T.C. Doesn't `A&` have to be an **lvalue**?

Comment: Actually yes, I should have written `const A&`. `A&` binds only lvalues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Calling `move(b)` returns an `rvalue`.
- Both `operator=(thing &&x)` and `operator=(thing x)` can accept `rvalues` as input.
- As such, the two overloads are ambiguous and the compiler rightfully complains because it can't choose between them.

Comment: +1 I get the second point (about rvalues as input), but what's the relevance of the first one?

Comment: @goldilocks the ambiguous call is at `a = move(b);` which is the same as calling `a.operator=(move(b))`. `std::move` returns an `rvalue` reference that refers to its input (i.e., `b`). The compiler sees that the return value of `std::move` is an `rvalue` reference and during overload resolution tries to find which overload is suitable for taking as input the result returned by `std::move`. Unfortunately, as @T.C already commented there's no rule to distinguish between the two overloads. Consequently, you get an ambiguous call error.

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem?